# I can't delete file with rm command as root

Tags: rm, delete

I am short on storage, so I tried to delete files, but I couldn't. It just gave me the following message:

```
rm: cannot remove .  ~ : Permission denied
```

In my case, I've accessed as `root`, and every file and their parent directory has 'w' (of course ownership is `root`). And most annoying one is that I can't use `lsattr` and `chattr`, so it's hard to check files attribute type. (`find` command is also denied.)

I checked past Q&A pages and tried their solutions, and everything goes to bubble.

Comment: Is the partition mounted read-only?

Comment: It would be good to add some keywords for what you already tried, so we don't need to suggest. What about `lsattr yourfile`? Did you do a file system check?

Comment: nope. i rechecked it and read-write both....

Comment: Is there a chance that the directory is a `btrfs subvolume`?

Comment: well what i've already tried - lsattr, chattr, chown, chmod, rm, and fsck...

Comment: um in case of **fsck**(e2fsck), i got _'command not found '_message....

Comment: What's the actual command that gave rise to the error that you posted?

Comment: GNU `rm `will always quote the name of the directory in the error message. It's unclear what the name is in this case, but it looks like it's `. ~` (dot-space-tilde).  What is the command that you used?

Comment: Kusalananda is right you should add the whole command you used to rm your file

Comment: Thank you to give me useful descriptions. I'm still not sure why did i get denied messages, but i solved the matter. When i tried to overcome the problem, I was working remotely. Ever since then, I retried it by directly accessing to hardware console. I just think it denies several remote commands. I'm really sorry to bother everyone because of lack of knowing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are also many files on the System that appear as regular Files but actually they are Links to Parts of the System Memory.
If you try to delete them it gives you an Error but that does not mean that something has gone wrong.

For Example `/proc/meminfo`:

```
# ls -lah /proc/meminfo
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 0 abr 11 09:57 /proc/meminfo
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        7992920 kB
MemFree:          143312 kB
MemAvailable:    4189992 kB
Buffers:              76 kB
Cached:          4506248 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
[...]

# rm /proc/meminfo
rm: ¿borrar el fichero regular vacío «/proc/meminfo»? (s/n) s
rm: no se puede borrar «/proc/meminfo»: Operación no permitida
# rm -f /proc/meminfo
rm: no se puede borrar «/proc/meminfo»: Operación no permitida
```

If you try to delete or copy a Directory it might give you a lot of Errors like this.
Especially in your Home Directory you might find a lots of Links to other parts of the System